# How to read HTML file only within a certain block in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to read an HTML file only within a specific block (jinja template) in python. I want to read between {% block content %} and it's corresponding {% endblock %}.

I am searching for {{ and {% between the blocks and I want to print the line number and the content of the line where I find the search patterns.

I save the file path in a variable and use it to open the file when I need. I use the enumerate function to keep track of the line number.

```py
fp = r"<path_to_HTML_file>"

def scan(line_number, line, flag):
    with open(fp, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for check_line_number, check_line in enumerate(f, 1):
            if check_line_number >= line_number:
                if '{%' in check_line:
                    print("Line Number: {}\nContent: {}".format(check_line_number, check_line))


with open(fp, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if '{% block content %}' in line:
            flag = 1
            scan(line_number, line, flag)
```

The issue I am facing is my code prints out all occurrences of {% that are present after {% block content %}, but I want to read till the corresponding {% endblock %}.

Also, I am not sure where to close the file.

Comment: Could you show the output your currently getting and the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be easily solved using regular expresions.

```
import re

# blocks will be a list of the contents of the blocks in the string FILE_CONTENTS
blocks = re.findall(r'{% block \w+? %}(.*?){% endblock %}', FILE_CONTENTS, re.S)
```

I strongly suggest you reading through the regex patterns. They are pretty handy.

Comment: Using regex I would get the search patterns. I am also interested in finding out the line number in which the match occurs. How can I find that?

Comment: Then I think it'd be easier to loop over each line and check with regex whether there is a new block. If there is then set a flag. If this flag is set then copy everything you read into a variable, let's say `block_text`. After finding the `{% endblock %}` set the flag to false.